# Trying to add reference in visual studio (c#), but there are no tabs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'd like to add reference to my Visual studio project. I'd like to add `System.Windows.Shapes`, which is probably in presentation framework. Everywhere on the internet it says, that it should be under .NET tab when adding reference, but I don't have any tabs when doing this. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You looking for reference in wrong tab. Look at Assemblies tab.

Comment: visual studio version ?

Comment: What version of visual studio you're using?

Comment: Nothing there. http://i.imgur.com/1BhsgxK.png

Comment: Assemblies and Namespaces are completely separate concepts. The fact that many core assemblies implement namespaces of the same name is merely a convenience. If you look at the documentation for any .NET framework class, you'll find that the namespace and the assembly are separately called out. So, e.g. [`System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System.Windows.Shapes` namespace, but in the `PresentationFramework` assembly. You add references to assemblies, not namespaces.

Comment: Visual studio community 2013 (12.0.31101 update 4)

Comment: This is because you're targeting Windows Phone... not everything exists for every framework... it looks like you already have the core Windows Phone libs. If we look at [`Ellipse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx) for example, it doesn't list it (under Version Information) for Windows Phone

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to know Marc Gravell.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for reference in wrong place. Look at this tab:

[image: assembly references]

[System.Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145013(v=vs.110).aspx) library contains [System.Windows.Shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

If you do not see such library check that you have selected the proper value in the Target Framework field (`Targeting`)